# Wrong Grouping in Extjs Group Sorting With Real Time Model Update

Tags: javascript, sorting, extjs, grid

I am using Extjs 6.7 Modern tool kit to write an app.

I group in [group-by] and sorting by [group-Update-Time]
in expect would look like the folloing, (every time I click [group-Update-Time] on the grid bar, it has no problem on sorting)

```
///////////////////
{
    xtype: 'Ext.grid.Grid',
    multiColumnSort: false,
    grouped: true,
    store: "itemStore"
}
////////////////////
{
    xtype: "Ext.data.Store",
    groupField: "groupBy",
}
////////////////////
store.getGrouper().setSorterFn((item1, item2) => {
    if (item1.groupBy == item2.groupBy) {
        return 0;  // same group
    }else{
        if (item1.groupUpdateTime > item2.groupUpdateTime) {
            return 1;
        } else if (item1.groupUpdateTime == item2.groupUpdateTime) {
            if (item1.groupBy > item2.groupBy) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
})
```

```
 [name]       [group-By]      [group-Update-Time]
----group 1----------------------------------------       
 aaaaa1           1               12:55:22
 bbbbb1           1               12:55:22
 ccccc1           1               12:55:22

----group 2----------------------------------------  
 aaaaa2           2               11:44:21
 bbbbb2           2               11:44:21
 ccccc2           2               11:44:21
```

When new update come in, my code will update all item that has the same [group-By]

```
// a listener function
onMessage(data){
   for(item in groupBy[data.id]){
      item.set("value", data.value);
      item.set("groupUpdateTime", data.updateTime);
   }
}
```

However, the grid will auto sort, and sometime look like below (random occur)
some items go to wrong group place, unless I click [group-Update-Time] on the grid bar again

```
 [name]       [group-By]      [group-Update-Time]
----group 1----------------------------------------       
 aaaaa1           1               12:55:22
 bbbbb1           1               12:55:22
 ccccc1           1               12:55:22
 aaaaa2           2               11:44:21
 bbbbb2           2               11:44:21

----group 2----------------------------------------  
 ccccc2           2               11:44:21
```

Comment: Which event call your `onMessage` handler?
On this `if`  control flow never hit to  `else if` block on your sorter function.
`if(item1.groupUpdateTime > item2.groupUpdateTime){
                return 1;
            }else if(item1.groupUpdateTime > item2.groupUpdateTime){`
You has identical condition for both

Comment: Please, create fiddle with your issues if you can https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/

Comment: Thank you @pvlt, The second condition should be ``` else if(item1.groupUpdateTime ==  item2.groupUpdateTime)```

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3325

Comment: I have created the real code example, and I simulate a real time websocket update via setInterval(), And I observant went I click  "updateTime" , "name",  "updateTime" , "name"... back and fort then will trigger the problem, And I am not sure the sorting order would affect "ASC" or "DESC". Thank again

Comment: I should say more clear: When I click the grid column title "UPDATE", "NAME", "UPDATE", "NAME" back and fort, the unexpected group sorting view occur